# Softlayer API to pull all invoices

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was successful in pulling an excel sheet from SoftLayer's API using PHP via

```
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$invoice = $client->getNextInvoiceExcel();
```

I write it to a location where it goes on a webserver and executes with a crontab.

I am trying to find out if I can also pull an Excel sheet for previous months. Through the Softlayer Web Portal, I am able to pull this information via manually selecting an invoice and downloading it to Excel. The problem is we manage several accounts and we'd like to automate using an id and api key to pull their previous month's invoices.

Right now I can only list them using:

```
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$user_bill = $client->getOpenRecurringInvoices();

print_r($user_bill);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SLAPI methods, it may help you: 
[SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/getExcel](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/getExcel).

First, you can get the invoices with: [SoftLayer_Account::getOpenRecurringInvoices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getOpenRecurringInvoices)

And then, with `invoice_ids` displayed in the last request, you can execute (Rest example):

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/[invoice_id]/getExcel

Method: GET
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Yes! That helps! I was able to pull it using php, but for some reason when I try to use curl to download and try to open it in excel, it looks garbled. Any idea what may be causing the issue?